# If the username or password is invalid when logging in, how can appear an error on page without refreshing itself, Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a login pop-up and I want after typing wrong username or password to appear a error message, like usual 'Username or password is incorrect', but after pressing button on the site, it is refreshing and I need to open my pop-up again in order to see the error, how can I do the error msg to appear without refreshing the page.

**Views.py**

```
def main(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if "register-btn" in request.POST:
        ....

    elif "login-btn" in request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username-log')
        password = request.POST.get('password-log')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/account')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password is incorrect')
            #here I don't know what to write for the purpose of appearing the 
            #error messages on the page without refreshing it

    return render(request, 'accounts/main.html', context)
```

**Main.html** ( briefly )

```
<label>Your login</label>
<input name="username-log" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your login">

<label>Password</label>
<input name="password-log" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password">

   {% for message in messages %}
      <p id="messages" class="xerr"> {{message}} </p>
   {% endfor %}

<button name="login-btn" class="btn btn_100" type="submit">LOG IN</button>
```

Comment: Use javascript.

Comment: @nigel239 what do I need to write in else statement to start a javascript function, in views.py?

Comment: Use browser side javascript. Submit the form to an API, if not valid, return error. Then show the user a modal or something based on the error.

Comment: @nigel239 I understood it, but not completely, It's okay to use ajax here like an API(I am not so familiar with APIs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that OP has the concern to inform the users about what's going on and decided to use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/) for that - that's great. Now the question that pops up is "How can one do that without the page refreshing?".

As [nigel239 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73692403/if-the-username-or-password-is-invalid-when-logging-in-how-can-appear-an-error#comment130132039_73692403), one'll have to go with asynchronous JavaScript. There are various Q&As articles that explain how to submit the forms asynchronously, such as

- [Django and AJAX Form Submissions – Say 'Goodbye' to the Page Refresh](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)
- [How to Work with AJAX in Django](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django)

Comment: Thanks a lot for URLs, you pushed my progress forward :)